# Transform extended FAB into standard FAB

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button

Did someone already achieved to transform an extended FAB into standard FAB and vice-versa ? I know how to add a FAB into my layout and how to detect the list scroll threshold but i really don't know how to achieve this transformation (Please see the reference to see what i would like to do : [Extented FAB into standard FAB](https://material.io/design/assets/1OTb9HPdZYx_7NVc3cizpA0T4ItMRb9Xi/efab-scroll.mp4)).

Thank you a lot

Kind regards

Comment: The Extended FAB for Android isn't implemented yet, look here: https://material.io/design/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#implementation

Comment: Thank you didn't saw this information !

Answer (score 5):

Just add 2 magical lines for this behavior this code only works for ExtendedFloatingActionButton

```
floatingButton.shrink(); ///This line of code hide text and show Icon of floating buttion

floatingButton.extend()///This line of code show text and icon of floating button
```